# How to terminate the connection between Observables and ovserver before all items are consumed

Tags: java-8, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I would like to know how can I terminate the connection betwen the observables and the observer early before all the obsevabes are consumed.
I know that it can be done through disposable..but how can I have a reference to disposable object givenas the below posted example
thanks in advance

**code**:

```
Observable<List<List<Person>>> observables = Observable.just(Main.getPersons());
    observables
    .concatMap(ll->{
        //how to display the size of List<List<Person>>
        //System.out.println("ll: " + ll.size());
        return Observable.fromIterable(ll)
                .concatMap(l->Observable.fromIterable(l))
                .filter(p->p.getAge().orElse(-1) <44)
                .map(g->g.getName().map(s->s+"_test").get()+ "  " + g.getAge().orElse(0));
    }
            )
    //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .blockingSubscribe(new Observer() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onError: " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onNext: " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't specify what condition you use to determine when you don't want to consume any more items. You can use `take(n)` to only consume the first `n` items, or `takeWhile()` or `takeUntil()` to check a condition. There are a number of other operators that could be used.

Comment: @BobDalgleish cant i do that using disposable?

Comment: You can use disposable to terminate it, but using `take()` and similar operators will provide more "natural" termination processes, since you won't need extra bookkeeping to hold on to the disposable.

Comment: @BobDalgleish i want to use disposable ...because i want to terminate the connection between the observables and the observer based on a  button click for an example

Comment: @Letsarmlt You can use the `takeUntil()` operator, which monitors a second observable and disposes of the subscription if the second observable emits an item or terminates. Make your button emit a value to an observable.